# Common source amplifier, source degeneration and determining the cutoff frequency

Tags: mosfet, feedback, high-frequency, cutoff-frequency, small-signal

I have a n-MOS transistor with the following biasing network:

[image: N-MOS]

I have to determine the cutoff frequency due to GS and GD capacitances

The method used by my book is to first redefine the transconductance as 
$$\frac{g_m}{1+g_mR_s}$$
to define an equivalent transistor without source resistance.

Then they compute the gain and apply Miller theorem to split the GD capacitor.
After that, the input pole frequency has been computed as

$$\frac{1}{2\pi\cdot R_g\cdot (C_{gd}'+C_{gs})}$$

What I don't understand is that \$C_{gs}\$ value used for the new equivalent transistor is the same as that of the old transistor.

Moreover they summed the two capacitances as they were connected in parallel. But the first is connected between gate and source and the second between gate and ground so they are not actually connected like that.

Am I missing something?

Comment: And who might “they” be? What new transistor and what old transistor?

Comment: "They" are the authors in the book, and "new transistor"/"equivalent transistor" is a known technique in CMOS where they replace the source-degenerated transistor by a new transistor with modified \$g_m\$ and \$r_{ds}\$ parameters to get rid of the resistor at the source.

Comment: Yes, basically, can you assume that the parasitic capacitances are the same for the equivalent transistor as the authors did? It was not explained and I didn't find any reference material.
Is there any underlying approximation other than assuming an infinite output resistance?

Comment: you can find detailed explanation and derivation in chapter 6: Discrete Amplifiers of the book Microelectronics by Sedra and Smith

Comment: It looks like I should borrow a physical copy of that book, since it looks like the part on transistor is quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

The first and only time I encountered this technique was [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6882877/). In that publication, they show how you can replace a transistor with source degeneration by an equivalent transistor using Norton's theorem:

$$g_m' = \frac{g_m}{1 + (g_{me} + g_0)R_s}$$

$$r_{ds}' = R_s + r_o + g_{me} r_0 R_s$$

Where \$g_{me}\$ is the effective transconductance when accounting for the body effect.

You are not missing something, I also believe that what they have done is probably not correct. However, it is also not easy to "compute" an equivalent capacitance to take its place. You can get expressions, but you will always find that the capacitance has some conductance in series.

You could approximate the gate capacitance however, by using Miller's theorem again. You can roughly compute the input to source amplification as this configuration acts like a source follower. You get approximately \$A_{in2s} \approx \frac{g_m}{g_m + g_{mb} + G_s}\$. You can then approximate

$$C_{gs}' \approx C_{gs}({1-A_{in2s}}) \approx C_{gs}\frac{g_{mb} + G_s}{g_m+g_{mb}+G_s}$$

As \$G_s\$ goes to a short-circuit (\$G_s \rightarrow +\infty\$), you see that the gate capacitance goes to its original value. When you have no body effect (\$g_{mb}=0\$), and as \$G_s \rightarrow 0\$ (a current source), you see that the gate capacitance is completely bootstrapped out. The source then moves along with the input voltage, and the capacitance never "feels" a voltage change and so acts like an open circuit.

Remember that this is still an approximation though. \$A_{in2s}\$ is not constant over all frequencies and we also haven't looked at the influence of the source-ground capacitance.

Comment: thanks!   It's still a "basic" course so they probably asked to use that approximation since we are still studying pretty simplified models (for example we always assume infinite gate and collector capacitances)